# How can i start a process in powershell another machine?

Tags: powershell, cmd, command, prompt

This code is works in cmd:

```
"C:\Program Files\...\.exe" /run Testv1 /resource machine:port /sso
```

How can i run it in powershell?

Comment: please have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6 ; example 7 should make it clear

Comment: Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\.\..exe" -ArgumentList "/run Testv1 /resoucres machine:port /sso" should works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\..." -ArgumentList "/run Testv1 /resources machine:port"
```

Or

```
& "C:\Program Files\...\.exe" /run Testv1 /resource machine:port /sso"
```